# .erb view does not contain variables ONLY after ajax request - Ruby on Rails - AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller set up like this (artists_controller):

```
respond_to :html, :js, :json

def entry
        #if AJAX
        if request.xhr?
            render layout: "ajax"
        end
        id = params[:id]
        @id = id
end
```

And a view that just has (views/artists/entry):

```
ID <%= @id %>
```

Route set up like this:

```
get '/artist/(:id)', to: 'artists#entry'
```

Javascript AJAX code looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/artist/137880',
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#main-container').html(data);
    }
});
```

When I access the page "/artist/137880" via a regular page request, it loads fine (ID 137880). However, when I access the page via an Ajax request, it loads the layout fine (aka no header and no footer), but the template only says "ID " and no variables are actually passed in from the controller.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize variable `@id` before calling `render`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was so obvious it's painful. I will mark this as accepted answer as soon as SO will let me.